# PHPMailer: Send emails to multiple recipients error

Tags: php, phpmailer

As in the title, I can't send an email to multiple recipients because I retrieve the following error:

> Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: You must provide at least one recipient email address.

I'm using this code:

```
$stmt=$db->prepare("select email from app_users where enabled=1");
if (!$stmt) {
  log_msg($db->error);
  die();
}
if (!test_execute($stmt->execute())) die("ERROR");
$emailto=fetchArray2($stmt);
$stmt->close();
foreach ($emailto as $contacts) {
  $mail->AddAddress($contacts);
}
```

What's wrong?

**print_r($emailto);**

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [email] => recipient1@hotmail.com
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [email] => recipient2@gmail.com
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [email] => recipient3@yahoo.com
    )
```

)

Comment: `$mail->AddAddress($contacts->email)` ?

Comment: You have an array of arrays, and you're only accessing the top-level array, so you're doing pretty much litterally the equivalent of `->AddAddress(Array())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Natrium nearly had it. You're not accessing your array elements correctly. Do it like this:

```
foreach ($emailto as $contacts) {
  $mail->addAddress($contacts['email']);
}
```

It's also a good idea to check return values, perhaps:

```
foreach ($emailto as $contacts) {
  if (!$mail->addAddress($contacts['email'])) {
    echo 'Address rejected: '.$contacts['email'];
  }
}
```

Comment: it works like a charm! Thanks for the solution and the good point about checking.